# Cloudsearch API 2013-01-01 cs.text_relevance replacement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a cloudsearch instance using API 2011-02-01, and I use a rank expression defined as

```
rank-faq-boost = cs.text_relevance({"weights":{"keywords":5.00}, "default_weight":1})
```

This would boost the score for any records with keywords field containing the search term. For any records without keywords they would still be returned.

the cs.text_relevance() function is no longer supported and I can't find the correct alternative.
I have tried to use

```
q.options={fields:['keywords^5']}
```

But that doesn't return any records that don't have any keyword fields, but have the matching search term in other fields, for example in the name field.
The only solution I can find so far is to list every field in the array, but this just feels much less flexible than the old way.

Does anybody know of the correct way to implement this?

Comment: I also faced such type of problem to pass all field in array. But not able to find out any solutions . Please send me solutions if you able to find . Thanks